# How to evaluate a move to a lateral position?

Tags: colleagues, career-development, promotion, politics

A colleague has been offered a lateral move.  They immediately said "no" because they believe a lateral move is always a step down, in the sense that the willingness to make a lateral move could signal to management or leadership that they can keep you by just moving you around rather than giving you a chance to truly advance your career.

While I instinctively disagree with this idea, I'm not sure that this viewpoint is completely wrong.

There are many ways to evaluate if another job is better or worse than the one you are in.  How do you take into account management's perception of the choice to move laterally (or not) on future opportunities?

This is in the US in the public sector.

Answer (score 4):

A lateral transfer *could* be an opportunity too - it could be that the new position has more opportunities for promotion than the last one did.

Plus, some companies like to transfer people from department to department every few years to:

- maximize how much that employee learns over the course of their career
- make them more well rounded
- avoid that employee becoming overly comfortable and complacent
- get fresh and new perspectives in departments that could otherwise be stagnant

Is any of that applicable to your company? idk. How long has your colleague been at this company? If he's been at this company for like ten years and has seen numerous people laterally transferred whilst also simultaneously seeing those same people denied promotions even years after the fact then that might be cause for concern. If he's only been at your company for three months or so then I doubt he has a large enough dataset to make an informed decision.

Plus, he could have always just asked his manager and the possible new manager as well. Sure, the managers could try to sugar coat it, but if you have so little faith in management that you take everything they say with a grain of salt then maybe you should start looking for a new job.

Comment: Yes, many legitimate reasons for moving staff around.

Answer (score 1):

A lateral move can absolutely be a positive move. If, for instance, the current team has very competent senior members, promotion prospects in the short term can be very limited.

I would personally view someone refusing to move laterally as someone that was happy in their current role, which is the exact opposite intent.

I would also view an employee that would prefer to operate on some degree of inference, rather just being honest and forthright about their career ambitions as obstructive.

I feel that "keeping employees engaged" is usually an incredibly rare reason to move people about, unless that person has specifically asked for a transfer. It's more likely there is some skill or staffing shortage that needs to be filled. Some people hate getting moved about, after all.

Comment: My experience is mostly skill or staffing shortage, usually when it's something more distasteful it's fairly easy to see.

Answer (score 0):

The public sector can be a little different when evaluating. Public jobs above entry level usually have a stringent requirements list, and, especially where there is a technical knowledge need/requirement, often hire from down below for positions above.

So, often you need a lateral move to gain the experience or become versed in said department/processes.

That being said, even in private settings, a lateral move is often needed to get promoted for the same reason and to get exposure to other business units and leaders throughout the organization. This is especially true if there is little opportunity for advancement in your current business unit.